# No button ripple effect when color primary, accent or warn, Angular 11, angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a simple 4 buttons, angular material,
imported BrowserAnimationsModule etc:

```
<button mat-button mat-raised-button > TEST </button>

<button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary"> TEST primary</button>

<button mat-button mat-raised-button color="warn"> TEST warn</button>

<button mat-button mat-raised-button color="accent"> TEST accent</button>
```

Only first button has ripple effect visible.
I tried to add class="mat-app-background" to the body or wrapper but still no effect.
Is it some kind of bug of this version ?

pure simple project, only angular-material dependency:
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9rbag?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Remove `mat-button` from `mat-raised-button`. It will work. Updated [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4zzrqu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: thank you so much, 1 day of trying so many things. And I swear I was comparing docs demo to my code and didn't notice no mat-button directive there.

Comment: I could add it as answer if you want.

Comment: sure, you can, it is an answer to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mat-button` directive from `mat-raised-button`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ripple effect by adding the following property too just in case you want to use only mat-button and not mat-raised-button

```
<button 
   mat-button 
   [disableRipple]="false"  // Add this line
>
  Some Button 
</button>
```

For mat-button, disableRipple will be true. So you can disable it and use the ripple effect.

I made the change here and you can take a look once if needed:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9rbag?file=src/app/app.component.html